# Wait in Main Thread for Quartz Scheduler to Finish

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have a Java application that makes use of a Quartz Scheduler in the guise of a [SchedulerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/SchedulerFactoryBean.html). The `main()` method gets the application context, retrieves the root bean, and commences scheduling jobs.

The issue is that the Scheduler runs in its own thread, so when the main thread is done submitting jobs, it returns and the Scheduler goes on without it. When the Scheduler is finally done (or even if you explicitly call `shutdown()` on it), the application just hangs there for all eternity.

I have two solutions:

1. Keep track of the job/trigger count, incrementing it whenever you add a job to the Scheduler. Attach a simple [SchedulerListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/SchedulerListener.html) to the Scheduler that decrements this count with every call to `triggerFinalized()`, and set up a `while` loop with a `Thread.sleep()` inside it that constantly checks to see if the count has hit 0. When it does, it will return up to the `main()` method and the application will exit normally.
2. Take the custom SchedulerListener from option 1, and keep track of the job count inside of it. Increment for every call to `jobAdded()`, and decrement for every call to `triggerFinalized()`. When the count hits 0, call `shutdown()` on the Scheduler (or not, it doesn't actually matter) and then call `System.exit(0)`.

I have implemented both of these independently in turn, so I know they both actually function. The problem is that they are both terrible. An infinite `while` loop polling a value? `System.exit(0)`? Bleargh.

Does someone have a better way, or are these seriously my only options here?

**Edit:** While thinking about this on the way home, I came to the conclusion that this may be caused by the fact that I'm using SchedulerFactoryBean. This auto-starts when Spring initializes the application context - that seems to put it outside the scope of the main thread. If I went with a slightly different Scheduler that I manually initialized and called `start()` on in the code, would this run the Scheduler in the main thread, thus blocking it until the Scheduler completes running all jobs? Or would I still have this problem?

**Edit:** Son of a...http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/examples/Example1

> To let the program have an opportunity to run the job, we then sleep for 90 seconds. The scheduler is running in the background and should fire off the job during those 90 seconds.

Apparently, that will not work, because the scheduler seems to always run in the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `SchedulerListener` add an object solely for synchronization and locking. Call it `exitLock` or something. You main thread retrieves the scheduler, sets up the listener, submits all the jobs and then just before returning executes

```
Object exitLock = listener.getExitLock();
synchronized (exitLock) {
    exitLock.wait(); // wait unless notified to terminate
}
```

On every `triggerFinalized()` call your listener decrements the counter for pending jobs. Once all the jobs have finished executing your listener shuts the scheduler down.

```
if (--pendingJobs == 0)
    scheduler.shutdown(); // notice, we don't notify exit from here
```

Once the scheduler shuts down it invokes one last callback on the listener where we notify the main thread to terminate and hence the program exits gracefully.

```
void schedulerShutdown() {
    // scheduler has stopped
    synchronized (exitLock) {
        exitLock.notify(); // notify the main thread to terminate
    }
}
```

The reason we didn't notify in `triggerFinalized()` when all the pending jobs were finished is that in case the scheduler was shutdown prematurely and not all the jobs were finished we would have left our main thread hanging. By notifying in response to the shutdown event we make sure our program exits successfully.

Comment: This looks like a much more elegant version of my Option #2. The `synchronized` blocks are blowing my mind, though. I see that they look like simple mutexes, and I know how the `synchronized` keyword works (one thread at a time, please), but I'm not 100% clear on what is being synchronized here. I assume it has to do with the fact that both the main thread and the Scheduler thread have a handle on the exitLock Object?

Comment: In my mind, the Scheduler and the Listener were in the same thread. The Listener has its own thread, then?

Comment: No listener is simple a floating piece of code first run under the main thread context. Then main waits. The scheduler thread after shutting down the scheduler runs the listener code in its own context and terminates. The main wakes up and returns. Program exits.

Comment: Ahh. The Listener is essentially being handed off across thread boundaries, so we have to `synchronize` on both sides.

Comment: I imagine your answer is correct - it certainly looks like it will work. I'll try it out on Monday...wait, no, American holiday...Tuesday, and accept it afterward if all goes well.

Comment: Yes but we usually synchronize to prevent a race condition i.e. to protect a shared state from becoming invalid. Here listener doesn't have a shared state as such but we're still synchronizing on the lock (which is a simple Object) because wait() and notify() can only be invoked on an Object whose lock has already been acquired.

Comment: After several tests, your solution was confirmed as working. Green check mark bestowed!

Comment: @RandomHuman Please consider (bestow :) an up vote as well if I was to the point but detailed enough.

Answer (score 2):

I think here can be another solution.

Key points:

1. When task was executed the last time `context.getNextFireTime()` returns `null`.
2. `Scheduler.getCurrentlyExecutingJobs == 1` indicate that it is the last executed job.

So when point 1 and 2 is true we can shutdown Scheduler and call `System.exit(0)`.
Here is the code:

**Listener**

```
public class ShutDownListenet implements JobListener {
    @Override
    public String getName () { return "someName";    }
    @Override
    public void jobToBeExecuted (JobExecutionContext context) {}
    @Override
    public void jobExecutionVetoed (JobExecutionContext context) {}

    @Override
    public void jobWasExecuted (JobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException) {
        try {
            if (context.getNextFireTime() == null && context.getScheduler().getCurrentlyExecutingJobs().size() == 1) {
                context.getScheduler().shutdown();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Code in the main function**
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Trigger trigger = ...
        Job job = ...

```
    JobListener listener = new ShutDownListenet();  
    scheduler.getListenerManager().addJobListener(listener);

    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
}
```

**NOTE**

1. I do not write `synchronized` blocks, but I tested this code with 100 concurent jobs, it works.
2. Did not tested in "complex" enviroment: clusters or RMI. (behavior can be differ).

Any comments are wellcome.

Answer (score 1):

If your Quartz schedules/triggers are based on the database then you program needs to be alive till you would want to stop it. This can be doable like below. The idea is hook [SchedulerListener](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/SchedulerListener.html) and wait in the main thread. You need to hook your own way to terminate the program gracefully which completely a different topic itself.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext =  // initialize the your spring app Context

    // register the shutdown hook for JVM
    appContext.registerShutdownHook();

    SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactory = appContext.getBean(SchedulerFactoryBean.class);
    scheduler = schedulerFactory.getScheduler();

    final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    final Condition waitCond = lock.newCondition();

    try {
        scheduler.getListenerManager().addSchedulerListener(new SchedulerListener() {

            @Override
            public void jobAdded(JobDetail arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void jobDeleted(JobKey arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void jobPaused(JobKey arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void jobResumed(JobKey arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void jobScheduled(Trigger arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void jobUnscheduled(TriggerKey arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void jobsPaused(String arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void jobsResumed(String arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void schedulerError(String arg0, SchedulerException arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void schedulerInStandbyMode() {
            }

            @Override
            public void schedulerShutdown() {
                lock.lock();
                try {
                    waitCond.signal();
                }
                finally {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void schedulerShuttingdown() {
            }

            @Override
            public void schedulerStarted() {
            }

            @Override
            public void schedulerStarting() {
            }

            @Override
            public void schedulingDataCleared() {
            }

            @Override
            public void triggerFinalized(Trigger arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void triggerPaused(TriggerKey arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void triggerResumed(TriggerKey arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void triggersPaused(String arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void triggersResumed(String arg0) {
            }

        });

        // start the scheduler. I set the SchedulerFactoryBean.setAutoStartup(false)
        scheduler.start();

        lock.lock();
        try {
            waitCond.await();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    } finally {
        scheduler.shutdown(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps someone else. I solved this by adding a shutdown-hook that triggers on Ctrl-C or normal kill (15) from script. A new Thread is spawned and polls the `getCurrentlyExecutingJobs().size()` every 3 seconds and exits when jobs counter has reached zero meaning all jobs finished.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    try {
        while (jobScheduler.getScheduler().getCurrentlyExecutingJobs().size() > 0) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        jobScheduler.getScheduler().clear();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}));
```

Answer (score -3):

```
 while (!scheduler.isShutdown())
 {
     Thread.sleep(2L * 1000L);//Choose reasonable sleep time
 }
```